# tentei fazer um pequeno programa apenas para aplicar logica, ele lê os dados mas não executa a operação que eu desejo

Tags: c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
char option;
int age;

```
printf("Wellcome Ladys and Gentlemans!");
printf("\nThis aplication is a surprise for you guys.");
printf("\nFor start the suprise a need to know something...");
printf("\nLook down and choose one option.");   
printf("\nOption <1> Toyota Supra. Option <2> Ford Mustang. Option <3> Nissan March Tuning 1.6 twin turbo.");
option=getchar();
printf("\nWe are almost there now I need to know your age.");
scanf("%i", &age);
if (age <=18) {
    printf("\n Sorry man, but we cant go on...");
} else {
    if (age >= 18 && option == 1){
        printf("\nYour Suprise is..... Tãdã a new Toyota Supra!!!!!!");
    }else {
        if (age >= 18 && option == 2){
        printf("\nYour Suprise is..... Tãdã a new Ford Mustang!!!!!!"); 
    } else {
        if (age >= 18 && option == 3) {
        printf("\nYour Suprise is..... Tãdã a new Nissan March Tuning 1.6 twin turbo!!!!!!");
    } else
        printf("Seeya my friend!!!");
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Quando você executa o código, o que acontece? Qual mensagem é exibida na sua IDE?

Answer (score -1):

O seu código precisava de alguns ajustes nas chaves dos if-else. Você também pode ler a entrada de opção como valor inteiro. O código abaixo funciona como desejado. Espero ter ajudado

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int option;
    int age;
    printf("Wellcome Ladys and Gentlemans!");
    printf("\nThis aplication is a surprise for you guys.");
    printf("\nFor start the suprise a need to know something...");
    printf("\nLook down and choose one option.");   
    printf("\nOption <1> Toyota Supra. Option <2> Ford Mustang. Option <3> Nissan March Tuning 1.6 twin turbo.\n");
    option = scanf("%i", &option);
    printf("\nWe are almost there now I need to know your age.\n");
    scanf("%i", &age);
    if (age <=18) {
        printf("\n Sorry man, but we cant go on...");
    } else if (age > 18 && option == 1){
        printf("\nYour Suprise is..... Tãdã a new Toyota Supra!!!!!!");
    }else if (age > 18 && option == 2){
        printf("\nYour Suprise is..... Tãdã a new Ford Mustang!!!!!!"); 
    } else if (age > 18 && option == 3) {
        printf("\nYour Suprise is..... Tãdã a new Nissan March Tuning 1.6 twin turbo!!!!!!");
            
    } else {
        printf("Seeya my friend!!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: aqui `if (age <=18)` o senão(else) para essa condição implica em `age > 18`. Os testes estão redundantes.

Comment: Isso `if (age > 18 && option == 1)` é desnecessário basta `if (option == 1)`  pois aqui `if (age <=18)` a idade já foi filtrada.